# Intuition behind the additivity of integrals over intervals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can one explain the property

$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = \int_c^a f(x)\,dx + \int_c^b f(x)\,dx\,?$$

Does it have any further meaning beyond the bald formula?

Comment: If $f$ is a nice function (say, continuous), it's easy to accept intuitively. The area, or net area, of a function from $a$ to $b$ is the sum of the areas from $a$ to $c$ and $c$ to $b$. If $c>b$ or $c<a$ the intuitive explanation fails

Answer (score 4):

If $c\in(a,b)$, then we can interpret that result in the following geometric sense :

[image]

$$\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\color{blue}{\int_a^cf(x)\,\mathrm dx}+\color{green}{\int_c^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx}$$

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that this identity only applies when $a<c<b$. This statement is true because an integral $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ finds the area under function $f$ over the domain of $[a,b]$. $\int_a^c f(x) dx$ finds the area from $[a,c]$, while $\int_c^b f(x) dx$ finds the area from $[c,b]$. Thus, $\int_a^c f(x) dx+\int_c^b f(x) dx$ is the same as taking the integral over the domain $[a,c]+[c,b]$, which is just $[a,c]$ if $a<c<b$.

Comment: It is not true that "this identity only applies when $a<c<b$. If $c$ is outside that range you get some "negative integrals" (the interval of integration is backwards) but the identity still applies.